# Как правильно выполнить метод через определенный промежуток времени?

Tags: c#

Помогите разобраться, как в С# правильно реализовать вызов метода через 60 сек? То есть запустил я, к примеру, программу, которая должна выполняться всегда, пока я сам её не закрою. Далее сразу выполняется метод, после его завершения ожидание в 60 сек. и запуск метода с начала. 
Мысли пока такие :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartProgram start = new StartProgram();
    while (true)
    {
        start.Circle();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
    }
}
```

Или :

```
TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(start.Circle);

Timer timer = new Timer(tm, null, 0, 60000);
```

Или как правильно крутить программу по кругу ?

Comment: Если промежуток между запусками равный, то таймер. Если 60 секунд после окончания предыдущего метода то Sleep() /Task.Delay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что правильный вариант 2.

В первом варианте, ты останавливаешь текущий поток целиком, а мог бы выполнять какую-то полезную работу. Можно, конечно, запустить отдельный поток и в нем делать `Sleep`, но для повторения одного и того же действия через равные промежутки времени, хорошо подойдет Таймер, чем изобретение велосипеда.

Во втором случае, ты подписываешься на событие, а события возникают в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, а вы не подскажите как реализовать обратный отсчет ? ну что бы видеть сколько времени осталось до обновления системы ? или например по нажатию 2-х кнопок ctrl+L программа выполнилась не зависимо от таймера, а таймер обнулился. Или мне создать новую тему ?

Comment: @Ethernets, лучше отдельная тема.

Comment: @Ethernets, по первому пункту, на вскидку: Сделать, что бы таймер срабатывал каждую секунду=>сможешь выводить сколько секунд прошло, а внутри метода анализируй прошло ли 60 сек или нет.

Comment: начал разбираться с таймером, и понял что он срабатывает каждые например 60 сек., а что если мой метод еще не завершился ? все начинается по новой, может есть способ как на время выполнения останавливать таймер, а потом его по новой запускать по завершению метода ?

Comment: @Ethernets, при входе в метод, Enable таймера в false переводи, а на выходе в true.

Comment: Тоесть я вас правильно понял, при входе в метод Circle я пишу следующие строки `Timer te = new Timer(); te.Enabled = false;` а когда я выхожу с метода то false меняю на true и будет все работать как нужно ? спасибо

Comment: @Ethernets, зачем создавать новый Таймер? используй тот таймер, которы ты ранее создал.

Comment: Вы меня извините я просто только учусь, не совсем понимаю как использовать таймер который я создал ранее в main в другом методе :( Извините за наглость, вы не могли бы показать ? просто мой метод используется в другом классе

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51129/discussion-between-ethernets-and-iluxa1810).